# In python How to unit test a tenacity library retry

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, retry-logic, tenacity

I have a function with tenacity library retry

```
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3))
def func():
    pass
```

How do I unit test that the retry will execute 3 times?
Thanks